# Can't import enum unless I made it const enum and set isolatedModules to false

Tags: typescript

I have a lerna monorepo setup with these packages:

- `@whatever/types` - with a single index.ts file:

  ```js
  export enum PetKind {
    Dog,
    Cat,
  }

  export type Pet = {
    kind: PetKind
  }
  ```
- `@whatever/api` - with a single index.ts file:

  ```js
  import { Pet, PetKind } from '@whatever/types'

  const pet: Pet = {
    kind: PetKind.Dog
  }
  ```

It's meant to be a Node.js application, so I have

```
type: "module"
```

specified in its package.json.

I can compile `@whatever/api` but when I run compiled script I'm getting this error:

```
import { PetKind } from '@whatever/types';
         ^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Named export 'PetKind' not found.
```

After some trial and errors I realised this happens because I import `enum`. I.e. if I get rid of it I stop getting error.

```js
// this works
import { Pet } from '@whatever/types'

const pet: Pet = {
  kind: 0
}
```

I also stop getting error if I replace `enum` with `const enum` (and set `isolatedModules: false` in `@whatever/api`-s tsconfig.json).

```js
// this works too
export const enum PetKind {
  Dog,
  Cat,
}

export type Pet = {
  kind: PetKind
}
```

I used following tsconfig:

- @whatever/types

  ```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": ["esnext"],
      "types": [],
      "target": "es2020",
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strict": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "noEmit": false,
      "declaration": true,
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "outDir": "./build"
    },
    "include": ["./src"]
  }
  ```
- @whatever/api

  ```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strict": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "noEmit": false,
      "declaration": true,
      "types": ["node"],
      "lib": ["esnext"],
      "target": "es2020",
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "isolatedModules": true, // I change it to false when I try `const enum`-s
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "typeRoots": ["@whatever/types"]
    },
    "include": ["./src"]
  }
  ```

Is there anything I can do about it? I don't want to use `const enum` for no real reason. From what I could understood it's generally not recommended unless there's a requirement to reduce a bundle size which isn't a case for me.

**UPD:** I think the issue is that I can't import any emitted code from my @whatever/api. I tried to export class from `@whatever/types` and I have the same issue on import.

Comment: What happens when you use this? `import { type Pet, PetKind } from "@whatever/types";`

Comment: @jsejcksn it changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in UPD it turned out that `enum`-s and `const enum`-s have nothing to do with my problem. The issue was I wasn't able to import any code emitted from typescript.

I was able to fix this issue by adding

```
"type": "module"
```

to package.json of `@whatever/types`

Comment: Apparently I have the same issue, but I am not able to fix it using your solution.

I can though import classes not just the enums, I can make the enums const and then import them but I don't want to.

Comment: This works 
import User from 'common/src/Entities/User';

But this doesn't 
import { UserGenders, UserRole } from 'common/src/Enums/UserEnums';